# Низкая скорость интернета на Ryzentosh Catalina

Tags: macos, wifi, взлом

Установил на свой комп Mac OS Catalina 10.15. Ещё мало разобрался в самой системе. Сама OS работает хорошо, только есть одно НО - скорость интернета очень низкая.

Включаю ПК, автоматически подключаюсь к Wi-Fi через Wi-Fi-адаптер TP-Link TL-WN722N, пользуюсь интернетом, примерно, час и после скорость снижается настолько, что страничка с Авито не может прогрузиться. Хотя скорость первый час была такой, что можно было на YouTube видео смотреть в 1080 и еще другие страницы загружать.

Может сталкивались с такой проблемой. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: А с чего решили, что это в компьютере дело? Проблема может быть и в провайдере и в роутере и в используемом софте. Исключите сначала провайдера и роутер. Потом уже смотрите через утилиту "мониторинг системы" куда и что лезет в интернет, забивая канал. Вообще может у Вас синхронизация и обновления скачивают много всякого забивая канал.

Comment: @Firsov36 провайдера и роутера сразу исключил, потому что на другом ПК (ноутбуке) скорость хорошая (установлена Windows 10), а в тоже время на Mac OS скорости вообще нет.

Посмотрел через мониторинг системы, там небольшой расход только на Safari и Telegram. Синхронизации, вроде как, нет. Apple ID не использую

Comment: Дальше надо исключать сам модуль вайфая. Брак никто не исключал. Может встроенную плату какую попробовать. Вообще эти мелкие адаптеры сотовой связи и вайфая любят нагреваться и может контакт слабым становится. У меня был случай, когда на двух пинах работало (не знаю как, сами офигели, но работало и медленно), может другие пины как раз искорка проходила. В общем если сначала работает как надо, а потом перестает, то тут скорее всего дело в железе.

Comment: @Firsov36 а не может быть такого, что провайдер считает мои данные как буд-то я пользуюсь через торрент? Я пользуюсь WiFi роутером от мегафон с тарифом, оплачиваемым на год. В нем запрещено скачивать через торрент. 
Или, может, драйверов каких не хватает?
Когда пользовался Windows 10 на этом же железе, то скорость была хорошей. Переустановил на Mac OS и пришлось докупить WiFi адаптер, т.к. для предыдущего не было драйверов. Пользовался один день и поменял TP-Link TL-WN722N, потому что скорость нормальной была полчаса, а потом такая же как и сейчас.

Comment: Я спрашивал про провайдера, и Вы же исключили его влияние?! Конечно он может резать трафик до 64Кб, как у них везде к тарифам подписано. Ищите "не публичные тарифы" для всех крупных сотовых сетей (в офисах не купите), там и цена раз в 5 меньше и безлимитный инет во всех смыслах.

Comment: @Firsov36 это как предположение, что по подобию торрента режут скорость. Если даже это так, то непонятно, почему они так делают, ведь торрентом вообще не пользуюсь, только браузером Safari. Подскажите, где можно поискать такие тарифы и есть ли к ним доверие? (не заблокируют ли или еще что-то)

Comment: Поищите в интернете прям по соответствующему запросу эти тарифы. Я не могу что-то подобное советовать, за что не могу отвечать. Доверять или нет, решать Вам. Изучите вопрос, взвесьте все за и против и примите решение сами. Но то что такие тарифы есть, это факт.

Comment: @Firsov36 спасибо за помощь. Поищу другие тарифы